# pandas: reshape multiple column features in related rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I've a dataset with n columns with identification data and x columns with attributes.
I would like each row to have identifiers and only one attribute. If an object has multiple attributes it will be present in multiple lines. What can i use? Thanks

In df

```
artist_name, country, album,song title...., extra artist 1, extra artist 2, extra artist 3,...extra artist 100
```

Out df

```
artist_name, country, album,song title...., extra artist 1  
artist_name, country, album,song title...., extra artist 2  
artist_name, country, album,song title...., extra artist 3  
...
artist_name, country, album,song title...., extra artist 100
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please add a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `df.melt()`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
                       'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},
                       'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6}})

pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A'], value_vars=['B', 'C'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The OP's question really lacks info, better not to guess.